# Getting E[Y|X] and E[Y] of joint PMF ${x \choose y}\frac{4}{9}^y \frac{5}{9}^{x-y}$

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

Let X be number of rolls till a 6. Next we choose with replacement X balls from an urn with 5 red and 4 green, Y is defined as the number of green balls sampled.

conditional PMF =  ${x \choose y}\frac{4}{9}^y \frac{5}{9}^{x-y}$

Get E[Y|X] and E[Y]

For E[Y|X] I got $\int_0^{\infty}yf_{Y|X}(y,x)dy=\sum_0^{\infty}y {x \choose y}\frac{4}{9}^y \frac{5}{9}^{x-y}$, which can't be integrated

Then for E[Y]
$E[Y]=\int_0^{\infty}E[Y|X]*P_{Y|X}(y,x)dx= [\sum_0^{\infty}y {x \choose y}\frac{4}{9}^y \frac{5}{9}^{x-y}]*[\int_0^{\infty}{x \choose y}\frac{4}{9}^y \frac{5}{9}^{x-y}]$

Is there a way to integrate these?

Comment: You shouldn't need any integrals since all the variables are discrete

Comment: And your PMF does not look like the joint prob. mass function for $X,Y$ but rather the conditional mass function for $Y$ given $X$.

Comment: Sorry yea that's what it's supposed to be. @pwerth it's not discrete is it? x and y are variables

Comment: @user8714896 yes there are infinitely many values, but it is still discrete because it is countably infinite

Comment: Pmf makes no sense without mentioning the possible values of $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

First notice that,  $$Y|X \sim Binom(x,\frac{4}{9})$$

Now for any $x$ the value of $E[Y|X]$ should be easy.

Second part you only need to use law of total expectation.

$$E[Y] = \sum_x E[Y|X=x]\cdot P(X=x)$$

I leave the rest for you to work on

Comment: I'm not given a specific x to find the expectation of it just says find E[Y|X] and E[Y]

Comment: I pretty much already give you everything. You only need to plug numbers. I could help you but this problem is rather basic and better left to you to try and practice your thought process.

Comment: @user8714896 If $E[Y\mid X=x]=g(x)$, then $E[Y\mid X]=g(X)$.